# How to select two rows that share a column

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has 5 columns, one of those is named country_visited and another one is called name. In one of the rows I have Mexico and Jose, in another row I have Mexico and John.  I want to retrieve back the country that both Jose and John have in common.

```
SELECT country_visited 
FROM table
WHERE name = "Jose" AND name = "John" AND country_visited = country_visited
```

Comment: Join the table to itself where country is the same and primary key (or name) is different

Answer (score 1):

Just use `HAVING` Clause with `COUNT(distinct name)=2`:

```
SELECT country_visited 
  FROM table
 WHERE name in ('Jose','John')
 GROUP BY country_visited
 HAVING COUNT(distinct name)=2;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7fde00179c14a656bb11206f0b94e563)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Just join with itself

```
SELECT t1.country_visited
FROM table as t1  INNER JOIN table as t2 
ON t1.country_visited = t2.country_visited AND t1. name = 'Jose' AND t2.name = 'John'
```

Comment: About 1st point you are absolutely right, I edited my answer, about second one it doesn't look so, because t1 has only Jose and t2 has only John, so if name + country key is unique there should not be duplication

Comment: *"because t1 has only Jose and t2 has only John, so if name + country key is unique there should not be duplication "* Anyhow SQL is a declarative language, where you defined what you get not how to get it..

Answer (score 0):

There are different answers to the query.

1. Using group by having clause.

   SQL> SELECT country_visited 
     FROM table 
    WHERE name in ('Jose','John') 
    
    GROUP BY country_visited 
    HAVING COUNT(distinct name)>1;
2. Using pivot (if your database supports) 
   This will help you analyse the rows which are for Jose and John individually w.r.t country_visited